# Is there any js function function to fetch the complete data from pagination

Tags: javascript-objects

My task is to enable the user to select only a single row from the entire table by using checkbox.

1. When user select any single row , checkbox for the other rows are disabled. But this is happening only on single page.
2. Since my table has large amount of data and pagination is applied. The above mentioned logic is functioning properly but when I move to other page of table , there user is again able to select some another row but this should not happen as the requirement is that user should only be able to select a single row throughout the table.

3)Help me out in telling that how to fetch the entire data from the table where pagination is applied because document . Get Element By Name only functions on single page and not on entire table

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable in the state `selectedRowId`, every time the table renders enable checkboxes on the bases whether `selectedRowId` is null or not.